# Does defineProps in script setup automatically create a local property of the defined prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

When we pass a prop to a component and define that prop from child component with defineProps a property somehow is created and accessible from child components template.

parentComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <child-component v-model="product">
</template>

<script setup>
import childComponent from "./childComponent.vue"
</script>
```

childComponent.vue

```
<template>
    {{ product }}
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['product'])
</script>
```

Here in childComponents template, the `product` can be accessed without needing to use `props.product` or toRef it. I know that script setup automatically injects the used props but I could not find any info (in docs) that the defineProps does some too. Is there any info about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [section](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#script-setup) :

> The script is pre-processed and used as the component's `setup()` function, which means it will be executed for each instance of the component. Top-level bindings in `<script setup>` ***are automatically exposed to the `template`***. For more details

Knowing that props are unwrapped directly inside the template and also the refs are used without `.value`.

If you want to reference some prop inside the script you should use `props.product` like in this example :

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['product'])

const total=computed(()=>props.product.quantity*props.product.unity_price))

</script>
```

if the prop is only accessed by template you could get rid off `const props` just call the macro `defineProps` :

```html
<template>
    {{ product }}
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps(['product'])
</script>
```